# Recover Jenkins from thinbackup not restoring ssh private key

Tags: jenkins, backup, restore

I am trying to restore my jenkins on new machine from thinbackup client backup.I also have backed up secret* and credentials file.

After restoring on new machine - most of the config looks good. The problem seem to be with ec2 plugin config where we have ssh key info, that looks like encrypted then thus fails. any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried restoring on same 2.32 & latest jenkins versions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be some vague issue.. it was pretty old jenkins setup..

what worked for me is to 
- update the key info again into the ec2 plugin "EC2 Key Pair's Private Key".
- backup again.
- restore from new backup on new mac.